# Yes, there is a portable charger on the table

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
               dt_object          MA
0    2020-01-03 10:00:00         NaN
1    2020-01-03 11:00:00         NaN
2    2020-01-03 12:00:00         NaN
3    2020-01-03 13:00:00         NaN
4    2020-01-03 14:00:00         NaN
5    2020-01-03 15:00:00         NaN
6    2020-01-03 16:00:00         NaN
7    2020-01-03 17:00:00         NaN
8    2020-01-03 18:00:00  255.544444
9    2020-01-06 10:00:00  255.136667
10   2020-01-06 11:00:00  254.585556
11   2020-01-06 12:00:00  253.975556
12   2020-01-06 13:00:00  253.463333
```

I want to Check Values in MA column for Rising or Falling and put results in new column. Can I do it without iterating? My current ugly way is looking like this:

```
compare = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i, 3] > df.iloc[i-1, 3]:
        compare.append('+')
    elif df.iloc[i, 3] < df.iloc[i-1, 3]:
        compare.append('-')
    elif df.iloc[i, 3] == df.iloc[i-1, 3]:
        compare.append('0')
    else:
        compare.append('NaN')

df['+/-'] = compare
```

Result is good, but I want to make it better and faster:

```
               dt_object          MA  +/-
0    2020-01-03 10:00:00         NaN  NaN
1    2020-01-03 11:00:00         NaN  NaN
2    2020-01-03 12:00:00         NaN  NaN
3    2020-01-03 13:00:00         NaN  NaN
4    2020-01-03 14:00:00         NaN  NaN
5    2020-01-03 15:00:00         NaN  NaN
6    2020-01-03 16:00:00         NaN  NaN
7    2020-01-03 17:00:00         NaN  NaN
8    2020-01-03 18:00:00  255.544444  NaN
9    2020-01-06 10:00:00  255.136667    -
10   2020-01-06 11:00:00  254.585556    -
11   2020-01-06 12:00:00  253.975556    -
12   2020-01-06 13:00:00  253.463333    -
13   2020-01-06 14:00:00  253.170000    -
14   2020-01-06 15:00:00  252.858889    -
15   2020-01-06 16:00:00  252.632222    -
16   2020-01-06 17:00:00  252.425556    -
17   2020-01-06 18:00:00  252.303333    -
18   2020-01-08 10:00:00  252.632222    +
19   2020-01-08 11:00:00  253.102222    +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `diff` method for that:

```
df['+/-'] = np.where(df['MA'].diff() > 0, '+', np.where(df['MA'].diff() < 0, '-', np.where(df['MA'].diff() == 0, '0', '')))
```

Comment: This is what I want, thank You.